# Solving constrained minimisation problem using unconstrained optimization of the generalized Lagrangian

Tags: optimization, machine-learning, constraints, karush-kuhn-tucker

My textbook, *Deep Learning* by Goodfellow, Bengio, and Courville, says the following in a section on constrained optimization:

> The **Karush-Kuhn-Tucker** (KKT) approach provides a very general solution to constrained optimization. With the KKT approach, we introduce a new function called the **generalized Lagrangian** or **generalized Lagrange function**.
>
> To define the Lagrangian, we first need to describe $\mathbb{S}$ in terms of equations and inequalities. We want a description of $\mathbb{S}$ in terms of $m$ functions $g^{(i)}$ and $n$ functions $h^{(j)}$ so that $\mathbb{S} = \{ \boldsymbol{\mathcal{x}} \mid \forall i, g^{(i)}(\boldsymbol{\mathcal{x}}) = 0 \ \text{and} \ \forall j, h^{(j)} (\boldsymbol{\mathcal{x}}) \le 0 \}$. The equations involving $g^{(i)}$ are called the **equality constraints**, and the inequalities involving $h^{(j)}$ are called **inequality constraints**.
>
> We introduce new variables $\lambda_i$ and $\alpha_j$ for each constraint, these are called the KKT multipliers. The generalized Lagrangian is then defined as
>
> $$L(\boldsymbol{\mathcal{x}}, \boldsymbol{\lambda}, \boldsymbol{\alpha}) = f(\boldsymbol{\mathcal{x}}) + \sum_i \lambda_i g^{(i)} (\boldsymbol{\mathcal{x}}) + \sum_j \alpha_j h^{(j)}(\boldsymbol{\mathcal{x}}) \tag{4.14}$$
>
> We can now solve a constrained minimisation problem using unconstrained optimization of the generalized Lagrangian. As long as at least one feasible point exists and $f(\boldsymbol{\mathcal{x}})$ is not permitted to have value $\infty$, then
>
> $$\min_{\boldsymbol{\mathcal{x}}} \max_{\boldsymbol{\mathcal{\lambda}}} \max_{\boldsymbol{\mathcal{\alpha, \alpha}}\ge 0} L(\boldsymbol{\mathcal{x}}, \boldsymbol{\mathcal{\lambda}}, \boldsymbol{\mathcal{\alpha}}) \tag{4.15}$$
>
> has the same optimal objective function value and set of optimal points $\boldsymbol{\mathcal{x}}$ as
>
> $$\min_{\boldsymbol{\mathcal{x}} \in \mathbb{S}} f(\boldsymbol{\mathcal{x}}). \tag{4.16}$$
>
> This follows because any time the constraints are satisfied,
>
> $$\max_{\boldsymbol{\mathcal{\lambda}}} \max_{\boldsymbol{\mathcal{\alpha, \alpha}}\ge 0} L(\boldsymbol{\mathcal{x}}, \boldsymbol{\mathcal{\lambda}}, \boldsymbol{\mathcal{\alpha}}) = f(\boldsymbol{\mathcal{x}}),$$
>
> while any time a constraint is violated,
>
> $$\max_{\boldsymbol{\mathcal{\lambda}}} \max_{\boldsymbol{\mathcal{\alpha, \alpha}}\ge 0} L(\boldsymbol{\mathcal{x}}, \boldsymbol{\mathcal{\lambda}}, \boldsymbol{\mathcal{\alpha}}) = \infty$$
>
> these properties guarantee that no infeasible point can be optimal, and that the optimum within the feasible points is unchanged.

I'm having difficulty understanding how $$\min_{\boldsymbol{\mathcal{x}}} \max_{\boldsymbol{\mathcal{\lambda}}} \max_{\boldsymbol{\mathcal{\alpha, \alpha}}\ge 0} L(\boldsymbol{\mathcal{x}}, \boldsymbol{\mathcal{\lambda}}, \boldsymbol{\mathcal{\alpha}})$$

has the same optimal objective function value and set of optimal points $\boldsymbol{\mathcal{x}}$ as

$$\min_{\boldsymbol{\mathcal{x}} \in \mathbb{S}} f(\boldsymbol{\mathcal{x}})$$

Specifically, I am not seeing how the latter claim that any time the constraints are satisfied,

$$\max_{\boldsymbol{\mathcal{\lambda}}} \max_{\boldsymbol{\mathcal{\alpha, \alpha}}\ge 0} L(\boldsymbol{\mathcal{x}}, \boldsymbol{\mathcal{\lambda}}, \boldsymbol{\mathcal{\alpha}}) = f(\boldsymbol{\mathcal{x}}),$$

while any time a constraint is violated,

$$\max_{\boldsymbol{\mathcal{\lambda}}} \max_{\boldsymbol{\mathcal{\alpha, \alpha}}\ge 0} L(\boldsymbol{\mathcal{x}}, \boldsymbol{\mathcal{\lambda}}, \boldsymbol{\mathcal{\alpha}}) = \infty$$

I would greatly appreciate it if people could please take the time to clarify this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting with:

> $$L(\boldsymbol{\mathcal{x}}, \boldsymbol{\lambda}, \boldsymbol{\alpha}) = f(\boldsymbol{\mathcal{x}}) + \sum_i \lambda_i g^{(i)} (\boldsymbol{\mathcal{x}}) + \sum_j \alpha_j h^{(j)}(\boldsymbol{\mathcal{x}}) \tag{4.14}$$

If the constraints are satisfied, then $g^{(i)}(x)=0$ and $h^{(j)}(x)\leq0$. Therefore, the terms with $\lambda$ all vanish, and the terms with $\alpha$ attain their maximum over $\alpha_j$ at $\alpha_j=0$ (because the last term cannot be positive), so also those terms vanish, leaving you with $f(x)$.

On the other hand, suppose a constraint is not satisfied. If $g^{(i)}(x)\neq 0$ for some $i$, you can let $\lambda_i g^{(i)}(x)$ go to infinity by letting $\lambda_i$ go to $\infty$ if $g^{(i)}(x)>0$, and $\lambda_i \to -\infty$ otherwise. Similarly, if $h^{(j)}(x)>0$ for some $i$, you can let $\alpha_j h^{(j)}(\boldsymbol{\mathcal{x}})$ go to $\infty$ by letting $\alpha_j \to \infty$.

Answer (score 0):

If $x\in S$ then $f(x) \ge L(x,\lambda,\alpha)$ for all $\lambda,\alpha$ with $\alpha\ge0$.

If $x\not\in S$ then one of the constraints is violated,i.e., $h_i(x)\ne0$ or $g_j(x)\>0$ for some $i$ or $j$. By taking the corresponding multiplier $\lambda_i$ or $\alpha_j$ large enough, one see $\sup_{\lambda,\alpha\ge0} L(x,\lambda,\alpha)=+\infty$.

Comment: But how do you reconcile your first claim with the claim that $\max_{\boldsymbol{\mathcal{\lambda}}} \max_{\boldsymbol{\mathcal{\alpha, \alpha}}\ge 0} L(\boldsymbol{\mathcal{x}}, \boldsymbol{\mathcal{\lambda}}, \boldsymbol{\mathcal{\alpha}}) = f(\boldsymbol{\mathcal{x}})$?

Comment: But that still contradicts $\max_{\boldsymbol{\mathcal{\lambda}}} \max_{\boldsymbol{\mathcal{\alpha, \alpha}}\ge 0} L(\boldsymbol{\mathcal{x}}, \boldsymbol{\mathcal{\lambda}}, \boldsymbol{\mathcal{\alpha}}) = f(\boldsymbol{\mathcal{x}})$, doesn't it? That's why I'm confused.

Comment: Also with regards to your second claim, why must it be true? It isn't obvious to me that a violation constraint necessarily results in $\max_{\boldsymbol{\mathcal{\lambda}}} \max_{\boldsymbol{\mathcal{\alpha, \alpha}}\ge 0} L(\boldsymbol{\mathcal{x}}, \boldsymbol{\mathcal{\lambda}}, \boldsymbol{\mathcal{\alpha}}) = \infty$, as is claimed?

Comment: If $x$ is feasible the $f(x) \ge L(x,\dots)$ and equality is attained for $\lambda$ and $\alpha$ being zero

Comment: The textbook doesn't claim that the equality is attained for only $\lambda$ and $\alpha$ being zero; rather, it says that the equality is attained **any time the constraints are satisfied**, so I'm still very confused about all of this.

Comment: Equality is between $f(x)$ and $\max_{\alpha,\lambda} L$ not between $f(x)$ and $L$ for arbitrary values of $\lambda,\alpha$.